# JNI - Throwing a Java exception from a native thread

Tags: java, exception, java-native-interface

What happens if one throws a Java exception using `ThrowNew` from a natively-created thread?

If the native code that throws a Java exception is called from Java, then the exception goes back to the Java side as expected, but what if someone calls this native code without directly or indirectly coming from the Java? It's not going to go back to the Java obviously, since we're not coming from there.

Comment: Well, if someone is not coming from Java, I'd imagine the ```JNIEnv``` they used as an argument would determine what happens.

Comment: Well assuming the natively created thread has been properly attached to the JVM, the JNIEnv would be the one returned by JavaVM::GetEnv().

Comment: It will go back to the `ThreadGroup` as an unhandled exception.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your help. Could you explain a bit more ? How is the flow behaving once JNIEnv::ThrowNew() is called ?

Comment: Correction, it goes to the [Thread.UncaightExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-) if there is one, otherwise to the `ThreadGroup`.

Comment: @EJP So you're saying that it "returns" to the Java code despite not actually coming from there in the first place ? Does it return to the native side once that handler is executed ?

Comment: No, I'm saying the exception gets reported to the [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-). Did you look it up? `ThrowException` doesn't return at all if I remember correctly, but you should look that up as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note**: This answer is outdated as of Java 9 (which was not available when the answer was written).

---

If native code is making Java calls, it must have called `AttachCurrentThread()` to obtain a JNI `env` value if the native code is called in a manner that it did not have a JNI `env` passed to it.

So, before the native thread or call ends, it must call `DetachCurrentThread()`.  But if there are any pending Java exceptions, `DetachCurrentThread()` will invoke the `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`, as posted by @EJP.

Per the [JNI specification regarding exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp17626):

> **Exception Handling**
>
> There are two ways to handle an exception in native code:
>
> - The native method can choose to return immediately, causing the exception to be thrown in the Java code that initiated the native
>   method call.
> - The native code can clear the exception by calling ExceptionClear(), and then execute its own exception-handling code.
>
> After an exception has been raised, the native code must first clear
> the exception before making other JNI calls. When there is a pending
> exception, the JNI functions that are safe to call are:
>
> ```
>   ExceptionOccurred()
>   ExceptionDescribe()
>   ExceptionClear()
>   ExceptionCheck()
>   ReleaseStringChars()
>   ReleaseStringUTFChars()
>   ReleaseStringCritical()
>   Release<Type>ArrayElements()
>   ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical()
>   DeleteLocalRef()
>   DeleteGlobalRef()
>   DeleteWeakGlobalRef()
>   MonitorExit()
>   PushLocalFrame()
>   PopLocalFrame()
> ```

Note that `DetachCurrentThread()` is not safe to all with any pending Java exception.

Yet a native thread that has [previously called `AttachCurrentThread()` must call `DetachCurrentThread()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp1060):

> **Attaching to the VM**
>
> The JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv) is valid only in the current
> thread. Should another thread need to access the Java VM, it must
> first call `AttachCurrentThread()` to attach itself to the VM and
> obtain a JNI interface pointer. Once attached to the VM, a native
> thread works just like an ordinary Java thread running inside a native
> method. The native thread remains attached to the VM until it calls
> `DetachCurrentThread()` to detach itself.
>
> The attached thread should have enough stack space to perform a
> reasonable amount of work. The allocation of stack space per thread is
> operating system-specific. For example, using pthreads, the stack size
> can be specified in the `pthread_attr_t` argument to `pthread_create`.
>
> **Detaching from the VM**
>
> **A native thread attached to the VM must call `DetachCurrentThread()` to detach itself before exiting.** A thread cannot detach itself if
> there are Java methods on the call stack.

So native code **must** call `DetachCurrentThread()` before exiting, yet `DetachCurrentThread()` can not be safely called with Java exceptions pending.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 and earlier, the only [JNI functions that are safe to call with a pending exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#exception_handling) are those which either release locks/references or themselves relate to exception handling. The idea is that when a JVM exception is passed to native code, it is supposed to either catch the exception itself or unwind the stack to a call frame that will. If a thread has no such call frame to unwind to, it follows that it should do the former. So the only specification-compliant way to handle an uncaught exception in a native thread was to clear it (i.e. call `ExceptionClear`) before calling `DetachCurrentThread`, perhaps after passing it to some custom handler.

In practice, if a pending exception made its way to the `DetachCurrentThread` call without being caught, the HotSpot VM has always handled them in the same manner as in JVM-managed threads, by passing it to the uncaught exception handler and terminating the thread. The problem is, the JNI specification did not offer a way for uncaught exceptions in native threads to defer to the JVM implementation’s uncaught exception handling in this manner.

This deficiency was noticed in two tickets: [JDK-8155881](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8155881) and [JDK-8179050](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179050), but requiring HotSpot behaviour was deemed too burdensome for other implementations. As a compromise, in Java 9 the JNI specification was amended so that [`DetachCurrentThread` is safe to call with a pending exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/design.html#exception-handling), but [the effect of this is implementation-defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#detachcurrentthread): ‘If an exception is pending when `DetachCurrentThread` is called, the VM may choose to report its existence.’. This wording [remains there in JNI 15](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#detachcurrentthread).

Long story short, if you just unwind the call stack while releasing all resources up to the point of `DetachCurrentThread`, you should *probably* be fine; with (a little) luck, the uncaught exception will be handled the same way as any other. But for extra safety, you should catch the exception yourself.